# How to privately reference another project from a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I'm looking for a way to 'privately' reference an MSBuild project so that it won't be shown to the user of the NuGet package. For example, suppose I have two libraries, **LibFoo** and **LibBar**. They're organized under a single solution, like this:

```
Foobar.sln
|
---- LibFoo.csproj
|
---- LibBar.csproj
```

Now, suppose LibFoo references LibBar. When I go to build LibFoo, LibBar is built as well. The resulting binaries are both included in LibFoo's output directory. When I `nuget pack` them and include everything in the directory as part of the NuGet package, LibBar's binaries are included as well.

Finally, when the end-user installs LibFoo, NuGet goes ahead and references everything in the package, **including LibBar**.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is not possible to exclude a dll directly but you can specify explicitly which assemblies should be referenced. This in turn does what you want since all not specified assemblies won't be added as a reference.

Have a look at this [section of the nuget docs](https://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference#specifying-explicit-assembly-references).

Comment: Awesome, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!